# How to adjust Playwright Codegen's locating priority/strategy in an Angular project with third-party component libraries?

Tags: angular, e2e-testing, playwright, angularjs-e2e, playwright-test

- This Angular project uses **Emulated ViewEncapsulation**, adds dynamically generated attributes like `_ngcontent-xxx-c001` into most elements, which absolutely can't be used in E2E Test. Fortunately, Codegen does not seem to pick these attributes as locator either. ✅
- We also use an internal **component library** which also generates dynamic id for elements like `<div id="#xx_auto_id_1" ...>`. However, in this case, Codegen has a strong preference for these attributes(id), which also leads to unstable tests. ❌

So I wonder if it is possible to modify Codegen's config so that it won't favor some locators like `id`? Otherwise is there a generator that better meets my needs? Selenium IDE? Or use Xpath?

Comment: You know that selectors don't only rely on their classes and ids right ? you can traverse an HTML tree with a lot of useful tools, such as `my-component > div + span:nth-child(3)`

Comment: @MGX That's not what they are asking. This is about playwright's codegen output. I just went looking for this and didn't find it. It would be nice to have a configurable preferred & exclusion list of locator strategies for codegen, for instance prefer `data-id` over classnames, or `aria-label` over text, or prefer to use classnames that start with `qa-` over others.

Comment: Related issues:
 * https://github.com/microsoft/playwright/issues/5178
 * https://github.com/microsoft/playwright/issues/19439

Comment: I was looking for the same thing to prioritize locators by role and label over id